# Send push notifications from azure hub to list of specific users

Tags: ios, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have 1000 users registered with unique user tag on my azure notification hub. Each minute I have to choose 100 random users and send them push notifications. What is the proper way of doing that? Do I have to make api call to hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(appleNotificationPayload, tagList) inside loop foreach 20 users so that there are 5 api calls for 100 users ?